# How often should NSManagedObjectContext save be called if inserting objects in a loop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I haven't found any guidance in the apple docs on how granular core data saves should be.

If I am inside a loop and inserting multiple new objects into core data, how often should I be calling `[NSManagedObjectContext save]`? Should I be saving in each and every iteration or only once after all the inserts are finished? What if there are 1000 objects to insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider the memory footprint vs performance when importing a considerable amount of data.

Take a look at [Core Data Programming Guide - Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1)

Comment: Thanks! Importing large data sets is a very similar problem domain to the one I was considering. Great info in that guide.